# HTML table display

Tags: html, firefox, html-table

This is what I want：

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |     |
|     |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|           |     |     |
|           |     |     |
+           +-----+-----+
|           |           |
|           |           |
+-----+-----+           +
|     |     |           |
|     |     |           |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

So I wrote the code below to achieve my goal:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="2"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But it didn't work,it display like this in Firefox:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |     |
|     |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|           |     |     |
|           |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |           |
|     |     |           |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

I don't find my fault, what should I do? Any help will be appreciate！

Comment: possible duplicate of [Firefox rowspan problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232337/firefox-rowspan-problem)

Comment: give &nbsp; white space inside the columns

Comment: which version of FF ur using...

Comment: FF version 17.0.1, IE9 dosen't work either. IE6 get worse...

Comment: add &nbsp; dosen't work etither.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing that requires any minimum height for the third row. Add such a requirement with a CSS rule, e.g.

```
tr { height: 1.3em; }
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. While it was being submitted I was off writing the demo: [before](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/ZBC6d/) and [after](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/ZBC6d/2/).

Answer (score 1):

#### This is not a firefox `rowspan` problem.

By default, the HTML is not in a position to handle because of equal number of rows, but different merges. One hack would be, using `<col>`, giving a fake column and hiding.

```
<table width="100%" border="1">
    <colgroup>
        <col>
        <col>
        <col>
        <col>
        <col style="width: 1px;">
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>​
```

Giving a `colgroup` and hiding the last `col` will do.

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sK6GG/

---

#### Another perfect approach:

```
<table width="100%" border="1">
    <colgroup>
        <col>
        <col>
        <col>
        <col>
        <col style="width: 1px;">
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="display: none;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="display: none;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="display: block; width: 0px; visibility: hidden; border: 0;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="display: none;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>​
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QvP77/

Comment: @Darkylin Added another approach. Check it out. :)

Comment: add CSS rules could also correct this error~ Anyway,thanks a lot!!