# html table layout again

Tags: html, html-table

This time I try to draw a table like this:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |           |     |
|     |           |     |
+-----+           +-----+
|     |           |     |
|     |           |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|           |     |     |
|           |     |     |
+           +-----+-----+
|           |     |     |
|           |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

I wrote my html code like this to achieve my goal:

```
<table id="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[Previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14099223/html-table-display) with style sheets as below:

```
td {
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
border: solid 1px #000;
}
tr {
height: 1.3em;
}
```

but this time ，it displays like this：

```
+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |
|     |     |     |
+-----+     +-----+
|     |     |     |
|     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |
|     |     |     |
+     +-----+-----+
|     |     |     |
|     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

What can I do now? Any solution will be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751127/how-can-i-select-first-second-or-third-element-with-given-class-name-using-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use [`colgroup`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/colgroup) and [`col`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/col) tag to define the width of the columns and not the `td`s directly..

```
td {
    height: 20px;
    border: solid 1px #000;
}
tr {
    height: 1.3em;
}
```

And

```
<table id="table">
    <colgroup>
        <col style="width: 22px;"/>
        <col style="width: 22px;"/>
        <col style="width: 22px;"/>
        <col style="width: 22px;"/>
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/wvGNn/1/

Comment: Yes, except that `colgroup` is not needed, and the widths of `col` elements are better set in CSS (where you can use various units). But the issue is that in the code in the question, there is nothing that sets a minimum width on the second column, so browsers may really minimize it.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela, not really.. the problem was the the `td` had a specific width, so  regardless of how many columns it spanned it became `20px` wide. In regards to the units, inline styles support the same exactly units as CSS rules do. But it should be in CSS indeed, to separate style from content..